# Combining two files into one in a specific format - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, web-scraping, scripting, formatting

I want to combine 3 files into 1 file in such a way format that it resembles

```
(file1,file2)
```

I have 2 files name.txt, price.txt

**Name.txt**

```
Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie
Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie
Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie
```

**price.txt**

```
Rs 288
Rs 288
Rs 288
Rs 288
Rs 159
```

What I actually want is that a new file `(deals.txt)` should contain the data from these 2 files in the following format

```
(Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)
#there should be a space inbetween 
(Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)
#there should be a space inbetween 
(Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288 )
```

I am using this logic but it doesn't fulfill the format that i want
`paste name.txt  price.txt >> price+name.txt`
it gives an output like:

```
Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie   Rs 288
Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie Rs 288
```

There is no space between the lines and no comma between the name and price. Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: please update the question with the logic you're using to match lines between files (is it based solely on line number?)

Comment: @Cyrus I am using this command `paste name.txt  price.txt >> price-name.txt ` but it gives an output like `Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie Rs 288` I need a comma between the name and price. And there should be a space inbetween one line and another line

Comment: @markp-fuso I have updated the code section. Please review.

Comment: you have 7 questions for the same problem now. why not read the whole data in one ride instead of separated in different files?

Comment: How would I do that? @alecxs

Comment: see the first of all questions

Comment: how do you know which price is for which product? line counter is not a guarantee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop-based solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for LINE in $(nl Name.txt |awk '{ print $1 }'); do
  echo "($(sed -n "${LINE}p" Name.txt), $(sed -n "${LINE}p" price.txt))"
  echo -en '\n'
done >> deals.txt
```

Will create a file `deals.txt` containing:

```
(Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)
```

Comment: `var = curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" | grep '<span>.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' > $var.txt`  I want to save the data from curl into a file with the name that grep grabs. Like if the `grep` command fetched `beverages` then it should make a file called `beverage.txt`

Comment: Then put your `VAR` between `$()`, like this: `var = $(curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" | grep '<span>.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g')`. Then you could run `curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" > $var.txt`.

Comment: Do I have to run `var = $(curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" | grep '<span>.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g')` and then run `curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" > $var.txt` separately?

Comment: Yes, because in the first case you are just declaring your variable to make it work later, not running it.

Comment: ```ARRAY=()
while read -r LINE
do
    ARRAY+=("$LINE")
done < URL.txt

for LINE in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do    
    echo $LINE
    var = $(curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" | grep '<span>.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g')
    curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" > $var.txt   done```   I am doing this but it isn't creating any file that var variable is fetching

Comment: Can you please elaborate the syntax you used? ```for LINE in $(nl Name.txt |awk '{ print $1 }'); do
  echo "($(sed -n "${LINE}p" Name.txt), $(sed -n "${LINE}p" price.txt))"
  echo -en '\n'
done >> deals.txt```

Comment: That command is just doing the following: for each line on file `Name.txt`, get the same line number of `price.txt` and print it right after the first one, together in the same line, and for each line, put a blank one between them (as requested).

Comment: 1- ```Name : Mc Crispy
     Price: 300 ```              If I want to have the text in this format what should I do?

Comment: how would I implement this format? number `1`  then  `name :` then on next line `price` then space then on the next line repeating the format

Answer (score 1):

One `sed` solution:

```
$ paste -d, name.txt price.txt | sed "/^,/d;/,$/d;s/,/, /;s/^/(/;s/$/)\n/"
(Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)
```

Where:

- `/^,/d` - delete lines that start with a comma (ie, no matching row from first file)
- `/,$/d` - delete lines that end with a comma (ie, no matching row from second file)
- `s/,/, /` - add space after comma
- `s/^/(/` - add left paren to beginning of line
- `s/$/)\n/` - add right paren and extra linefeed (`\n`) to end of line

---

One `awk` solution:

```
$ paste -d, name.txt price.txt | awk -F"," '$1=="" { next } $2=="" { next } { printf "(%s, %s)\n\n",$1,$2 }'
(Cappuccino with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Cappuccino with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Latte with Milk Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)

(Latte with Double Chocolate Cookie, Rs 288)
```

Where:

- `-F ","` - use comma as input field delimiter
- `$1=="" { next }` - if first field is blank then skip line (ie, no matching row from first file)
- `$2== "" { next }` - if second field is blank then skip line (ie, no matching row from second file)
- `printf ...` - print line with parenthesis wrappers, comma+space delimiter, and extra linefeed on the end

Comment: `var = curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" | grep '<span>.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' > $var.txt`  I want to save the data from curl into a file with the name that grep grabs. Like if the `grep` command fetched `beverages` then it should make a file called `beverage.txt`

Comment: ```1- Name : Mc Crispy
     Price: 300```  how would I implement this format? `name :` then on next line `price` then space then on the next line repeating the format

Comment: I would suggest creating new questions to address new requirements ... as opposed to increasing/modifying the scope of the current question